# Dealing with git problem in Alexa Skill in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, alexa-skills-kit

I’m writing an Alexa-hosted Skill (Node.js) using git-enabled Visual Studio Code on a Mac. But I’ve hardly started before I find the code editor in the Amazon Developer Console is locked with the message “The master branch of your skill is ahead of the dev version. To re-enable the code editor, you need to use the ASK CLI to merge the remote master branch to dev and push.”

I’m at a loss what to do. VSC says it no longer depends on ASK CLI and I don’t have it installed. A search of the web has not helped. I feel sure that an experienced developer could deal with this in two minutes.  Any advice appreciated.

I’m a newcomer to all three of VSC and Git and Alexa Skills (particularly to git), so excuse me if this is a trivial question.

Comment: You *probably* don't need ASK CLI. Try to merge the `master` branch to `dev` and push.

Comment: Thanks @phd, the thing is the git repo on my local Mac has branches ‘master’ and ‘prod’ (no ‘dev’ branch).  I think ‘dev’ must be a branch on the Amazon-hosted remote repo. Does it mean I should do that merge between ‘dev’ and ‘master’ in the remote repo? I think that repo is called ‘origin’. Not confident on how to do that. It gives some warning about ‘HEAD’ when I go there.

Comment: "*Does it mean I should do that merge between ‘dev’ and ‘master’ in the remote repo?*" Yes if you can do it remotely. If you cannot fetch the `dev` branch to your local repo: `git fetch origin dev:dev`

Comment: WOW! That did it @phd. Many thanks! I fetched the remote branch `dev, as you suggested, then merged it with the local `master`, then pushed it. And when I checked the Amazon Developer Console the Node.js file was up to date and the editor unlocked. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

No need to make any changes. This is an intermediate state of the code for Alexa where you my have just pushed your current master branch. Wait a while and refresh the page. It should be in deploying state after a few minutes.